# After downloading "Windows SDK Installer for windows 10" i cannot find the inspect tool in Windows Kits folder

Tags: windows, selenium, testing, winappdriver, desiredcapabilities

I have downloaded windows SDK Installer from the following URL "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/"

I have downloaded in my downloads folder. when I open the windows kits folder> 10 > Windows SDK, I can only see the following folders. Here there is no inspect tool. Can anyone know the solution for this problem.

After opening the windows SDK the folder structure looks like :
          Installers (Folder)
          Redistributable (Folder)
          User Experience manifest (XML Document)
          WinsdksetUp (Application)

Answer (score 1):

I just checked on my machine and my Inspect.ext is at:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86\inspect.exe"`

all other `<version>` folders are nearly empty on my machine as well. Hopefully this helps. The only other thing I can think of - and it may not matter for this issue - is to have developer mode enabled on your machine. Just search "developer mode" and it should come up.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\<version>\<platform>`

[image]

As per [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects), you might be better off with [Accessibility Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/) as the modern replacement.